# raise radiobutton CheckedChanged from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function  that response to a click of `<tr>` and check a "asp:radiobutton"

the radiobutton attribute, "autopostback" is set to "true",however the javascript function that check the radiobutton don't fire the event of the radiobutton "radiobutton_CheckedChanged"

What can I do in order to fire the radiobutton event after it was checked by the javascript function?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Does it autopostback if you just click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
 setTimeout('__doPostBack(\"<%=rb2.ClientID %>",\'\')', 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/MethodsandPropertiesoftheRadioObject.htm) will let yoy know that radio button has not any radiobutton_CheckedChanged event. However you can use click event and 
Property checked  achive what you want and write return true to postback page the due to autopostback true attribute and write return false to not to postback the page in java script function.

Comment: I found the answer: setTimeout('__doPostBack(\"<%=rb2.ClientID %>",\'\')', 0);